# R function like which to match multiple inputs to multiple values

Tags: r, lookup

I have a vector of multiple values that I want to match to multiple values without the use of a loop.  Is there a function that can do this?

```
x <- c(2,5,4)
y <- 2:10
which(x==y) #won't work
```

Expected output is 1,4,3

In my real use case, you can assume that there is only 1 correct match and it will match y every time.  I need this to be as fast as possible, that's why I'm trying to avoid a loop.  As a side note, this part is already inside of a foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

You want `match`

```
match(x,y)

# 1 4 3
```

Comment: I don't have the rep to upvote, but tried.  Thank you.  It was also quite a bit faster than a loop as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The `which()` version would be `which(x %in% y)`. But I don't think this fits for your purpose as the expected output is `1,2,3`.

But if you apply `which(y %in% x)` than your output will be `1,3,4`